# Insertion sort not sorting correctly

Tags: algorithm, scala, insertion-sort

I have this insertion sort written in Scala:

```
def insertionSort(array:Array[Double]):Unit ={
    for(i <- 1 until array.length){
      var current = i - 1
      var currentTemp = array(i)
      do{
        array(current + 1) = array(current)
        current -= 1
      }while((current >= 0 && currentTemp < array(current)))
      array(current + 1) = currentTemp
    }
    }
```

I noticed that when I run the function, I get back the a sorted list except for the last number. Here is the output:

```
Unsorted Array: 0.447256485852796,0.5849012754409237,0.4132227916845631,0.5850539272085894,0.38731662469810446
Insertion Sorted Array: 0.38731662469810446,0.4132227916845631,0.5849012754409237,0.5850539272085894,0.447256485852796
```

I'm not sure what I can change so the last number is in its proper position. Any help would be great.

Comment: HINT: What's the key difference between a `while()` loop and a `do ... while()` loop?

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for hint. I always thought that you could use a while and do...while loop interchangeably without changing the output.

Comment: Ah, if they were interchangeable we wouldn't need to have both and we wouldn't see one used 99% more often than the other.